# SAP Flight reservation application

Tags: abap

I am accessing flight reservation application built in SAP.

The application has a section on catering which contains: BC_MEAL, BC_MEALT, BC_STARTER, BC_MAINCOURSE, BC_DESSERT.

However, there are no such tables prefixed with BC_.

The tables are SMEAL, SMEALT, SSTARTER, SMACOURSE, SDESSERT instead.

Why is this discripency due to? How does SAP manage to convert application names into table names.

[image: Flight Reservation Demo Application]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at the Data Modeler (SD11) and trying to compare it to the Data Dictionary / ABAP Dictionary (SE11). The actual table names are assigned to the entities explicitly:

- expand `BC_FLIGHT`
- double-click on `BC_SFLIGHT`
- Button `Dict.` (?)
- --> This screen should show the tables and/or views used to represent the entity.

It is worth noting that for many applications, no explicit data model exists (which is why I personally never bothered with the Data Modeler - a tool like this is virtually useless unless everyone else uses it as well).